# what is APPPATH in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is an example.

```
class My_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    parent::__construct();
    include(APPPATH.'config/jscss.php');
}
```

what is the 'APPPATH' above?

Comment: `Application Path Folder`

Comment: So many answers were needed to explain what `APPPATH` means! It's just `APP` `PATH`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**APPPATH** is your **application** folder

Copy `jscss.php` file to `/application/config/` folder.

```
/application
  - /config
     - jscss.php
  - /controllers
  - /cache
  - /core
  - etc..
/system
index.php
```

Answer (score 3):

### Description

`APPPATH` is a codeigniter *constant*. It contains value of the full path to your `application` folder.

### Value

```sh
/path/to/your/codeigniter/application/
```

Note: The value of the constant has a slash character `/` at the end. This is crucial for concatenation purposes.

Answer (score 3):

APPPATH is defined in index.php:

```
define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 2):

path to your application folder.

Answer (score 2):

Path upto your `Application` folder

Answer (score 1):

PAth on your Application->Your Project