# How to fetch the folder names in codeigniter "views" folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, view, directory

I am trying to get folder names in codeigniters' "views" folder to create a kind of template class that will fetch all folder names in "view"...

I actually want to create a default template for my site and then be able to change it just by adding another template folder like wordpress themes

how do I do that?

If you could hopefully understand what I want to say here...

```
?php       

// declare the folder    
$ourDir = "/home/public_html/folderName";

// prepare to read directory contents    
$ourDirList = @opendir($ourDir);

// loop through the items    
while ($ourItem = readdir($ourDirList))    
{        
   // check if it is a directory    
   if (is_dir($ourItem))    
   {    
      echo "directory: $ourItem <br />";    
   }

   // check to see if it is a file    
   if (is_file($ourItem))    
   {    
      echo "file: $ourItem <br />";    
   }    
}

closedir($ourDirList);
```

?>

tried this but doesn't work.. :(

Comment: Did you get any error? What you get when you run it?

Comment: You maybe want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850535/what-is-apppath-in-codeigniter, but, rather than that approach, could i suggest something else? Theme names/ids/other data... should be stored in database (you will need it anyway). Theme names should be equal to folder names in your views folder... and when you need/select another theme, you can easily get it with: $this->load->view('themes/theme_from_db); in your controllers... To list it, where you need it, just list db entries, with appropriate image....

Comment: Actually i get nothing just blank page

Comment: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given this is the error i get now .. and same with the closedir()

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the additional information you're supplying in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Well i just found my ans ...

```
<?php
$dir =  APPPATH.'views/';

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if(filetype($dir . $file) == 'dir' && $file != '..' && $file != '.') {
                echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "<br>";
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

This will echo out all the folders...